# How to make viso2_ros work with realsense r200?

Tags: ros

I have been trying to make viso2_ros work with intel realsense r200. But there is a problem with the synchronisation(I think) and viso2_ros is not getting any image data. I get the following warning:

[image]
Following is my launch file:

```html
<launch>
<arg name="camera" default="stereo_forward"/> <node ns="$(arg camera)" pkg="stereo_image_proc" type="stereo_image_proc" name="stereo_image_proc"/> --> <node pkg="viso2_ros" type="stereo_odometer" name="stereo_odometer" output="screen">

    <remap from ="stereo" to="$(arg camera)"/>
    <remap from="image" to="image_rect"/>
    <remap from="/$(arg camera)/left/image_rect"           to="/camera/ir/image_raw"/>
    <remap from="/$(arg camera)/left/camera_info"  to="/camera/ir/camera_info"/>
    <remap from="/$(arg camera)/right/image_rect"       to="/camera/ir2/image_raw"/>
    <remap from="/$(arg camera)/right/camera_info" to="/camera/ir2/camera_info"/>
        <remap from="odom" to="/stereo_odometer/odometry"/>
            <param name="queue_size" type="int" value="100"/>
    <param name="approximate_sync" type="bool" value="true"/>
    <param name="base_link_frame_id" value="$(arg camera)"/>
    <param name="odom_frame_id" value="/odom"/>
</node>
</launch>
```

The rqt_graph:

[image]

which does not show a connection for /stereo_forward/right/image_rect. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with ROS Kinetic. If anyone has any idea or suggestion about a resolution, I would really appreciate that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you see the images you are publishing on /camera/ir/image_raw and /camera/ir2/image_raw on rqt_image_view ??

Comment: Yes. I can see those images.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick google search it looks like Intel R200 only has 1 RGB camera. So I think you'd have to use monocular VO.

Comment: Hello Vik, I tried using monocular VO but it did not help much. Also, R200 should work with stereo odometry. See this [implementation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTgpMFCL6Pg). I still think the problem is because of the synchronisation. I am trying to synchronise two IR cameras with image_transport now. Do let me know if you have any other suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: As your error message suggests, have you tried setting the approximate_time_sync flag to True?

Comment: Yes. I have tried that along with the other two suggestions. Rosnode info does show connections and changing queue size did not help.

Comment: Try checking the difference in timestamps between images in each topic.  You can use `rostopic echo /stereo_forward/left/image_rect --noarr` No array flag hides the image array so you can see the headers.